# Processors without client_id in revision allows no PUT-updates via the REST-API

Tags: python, rest, apache-nifi

I want to update the state of a processor. I can successfully retrieve the current state of a processor with a `GET` request on `/nifi-api/processors/proc_id`.

I get the following JSON back:

```
{"revision":{"version":1},"id":"cd55-processor-id-03ab4","uri":" ..." ....
```

The problem occurs during the `PUT` on `/processors/{id}/run-status` when I try to write a new state back to Nifi - I receive the following error:

```
b'Node [....] is unable to fulfill this request due to: [3, cd55-processor-id-03ab4] 
    is not the most up-to-date revision. This component appears to have been modified'
```

My code:

```
# Get node for current version
response = requests.get(url_nifi_api + f'processors/{processor_id}'
                        , headers=header
                        , verify=False)
processor = json.loads(response.content)
# increment for new state
proc_version_inc = processor['revision']['version'] + 1 
put_dict = {"revision": {"version": proc_version_inc}, "state": new_state, "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": True}  

payload = json.dumps(put_dict).encode('utf8')
response = requests.put(url_nifi_api + 'processors/' + processor_id + '/run-status', headers=header, data=payload)
```

So I figured the problem is that I need to pass `clientId` in the revision (despite the [docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) saying it is an optional attribute) - but the processor doesn't have a client-ID.

Here is my code with a client ID - **this works for processors where a client-ID exists in the `GET` JSON.**

```
processor= json.loads(requests.get(url_nifi_api + f'processors/{processor_id}'
                        , headers=header
                        , verify=False).content)
# get result for instance:  {"revision":{"clientId":"60b-00d0-client-id-37c","version":4}, ....

client_id = processor['revision']['clientId']
proc_version_inc = processor['revision']['version'] + 1  # in this example: 4+1
put_dict = {"revision": {"clientId": client_id, "version": proc_version_inc}, 
            "state": new_state, "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": True}
```

The only difference between this and the other processor is, that the other processors has no `clientId` in the processor's `GET` JSON. But even if I explictely set `clientId` to an empty String (or copy it from a processor with an existing `clientId`), it just gives me the same error.

The only solution I found so far is to *manually* change the processor in the Web-UI, after which the processor has a client-id and the code works by . I really don't want to do this every time the error occurs. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think problem in version. What value you have in proc_version_inc var?

Comment: Where should I find this version? There exists no such variable in the JSON returned by `GET` on the processor.

Comment: Ah, you mean my variable.  `proc_version_inc`  is the version number I retrieve from processor during the `GET` request and incremented by `1`.

Comment: @Cribber you shouldn’t increment version , nifi does that.  just send what you get from get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, @yaprak was right in the comments - sending the un-incremented version number back worked. The behavior is a bit weird though, so I guess the easiest way is to never change the `revision` of a processor manually.

1. If there exists a `clientId` *and* a `version-number`, then you can increment the version manually as much as you want.
2. If there exists **no** `clientId` and only a `version-number`, then Nifi does not allow any incrementation of the versions.